# Finite State Machine implementation in python (switch case)

Tags: python-2.7

when I code in C, i use big switch/case to implement my FSM(Finite State Machine), 
while python doesn't provide that. it has been suggested to use dictionary or if/else clauses, but these solutions doesn't seem to be as efficient as switch/case clauses are. is there any other way to implement FSM in python?

Comment: you can use if else instead of switch. If your question related to switch

Comment: Sadly there isn't any case/switch statement in Python, the development team decided to ditch the idea years ago, as you can see in this bug from 2006: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103/ - as we all know a nice case/switch (not the dict solution) will make the language nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution for switch case in python is **dictionary mapping**. 
It is very efficient, and you can see it looks clean:

```
def zero():
    return "0"

def one():
    return "1"

def two():
    return "2"

def num_to_func_to_str(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: zero,
        1: one,
        2: two,
    }

    # get the function based on argument
    func = switcher.get(argument)

    # Execute the function
    return func()
```

This pattern allows you more functionality than switch statement; because you are retrieving the function first, it allows you inspect / manipulate it - before executing it.

Another option is to implement a **switcher class.**

```
class Switcher(object):
    def num_to_methods_to_str(self, argument):

        method_name = 'number_' + str(argument)
        method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: "nothing")
        return method()

    def number_0(self):
        return "zero"

    def number_1(self):
        return "one"

    def number_2(self):
        return "two"
```